# Reporting Services table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

*(Image removed due to [ImageShack replacing it with advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468))*

I'm trying to acheve the above in reporting services. Current month is fine but how can i add prev month to the table? The data is currently stored in a different dataset that has exactly the same fields.

Using reporting services 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing this in the query that returns data to Reporting Services?

Answer (score 0):

You need one dataset per table/control in reporting services. Otherwise you would have to use aggregation logic in the expression to join the data which means you would have to pivot your previous month dataset.

If you can get the previous month data in the same dataset, go with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the data to be in a single dataset you could then put this in a matrix table, grouping by the previous month and current month.  If you want a regular table you could do the same return in a single dataset and set up Groups for Current Month and Previous month.